# Accessing members of a jsclass Set in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get a specific element from a set in jclass set.
There is how to add but not how to get. Even if I try

```
        var oo = new Set([2,4,6,8]);
    alert("ok?"+oo.get(2));
```

I'v also tryed to acces like an array

```
        var oo = new Set([2,4,6,8]);
    alert("ok?"+oo[2]);
```

both of them  failed

docs: http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/set.html

Comment: You don't seem to get the concept of a [*Set*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(computer_science)). What do you mean by "specific"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of .toArray()

```
    var oo = new Set([2,4,6,8]);

    alert("ok?"+oo.toArray()[0]);
```